# How can I get the word under the cursor and the text of the current line in Vimscript?

Tags: vim, scripting

I'm writing a Vim script. How can I get the word under the cursor and the text of the current line?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can with [expand](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expand()) and [getline](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#getline()):

```
let wordUnderCursor = expand("<cword>")
let currentLine   = getline(".")
```

Comment: Use `help cword` to get more options. For my vimrc, I needed `cWORD` to grab the whitespace delimited text under the cursor

Comment: for me `getline(".")` gives the same result as `expand("<cword>")`. i want to grab the entire line under cursor. how do i do that?

Comment: Further to @Ben's comment, you can observe the difference between where the cursor jumps to for `cword` and `cWORD` by pressing `w`  and `W` on one's keyboard while in normal mode.