# How to get text-object under cursor via vim script?

Tags: vim

I've found answers for how to get [the word/WORD under the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115447/how-can-i-get-the-word-under-the-cursor-and-the-text-of-the-current-line-in-vim) or [the character under the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560911/vim-do-something-in-a-function-based-on-character-under-a-cursor), or the whole line (`getline(".")`). How can I get a given text-object under the cursor?

More specifically, I want to get what would be selected by `vi'`, and use that characters in a function (without messing up the registers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and most straightforward is indeed by yanking to a register; just make sure you save and restore the original contents.

```
let l:save_clipboard = &clipboard
set clipboard= " Avoid clobbering the selection and clipboard registers.
let l:save_reg = getreg('"')
let l:save_regmode = getregtype('"')
normal! yi'
let l:text = @@ " Your text object contents are here.
call setreg('"', l:save_reg, l:save_regmode)
let &clipboard = l:save_clipboard
```

Comment: Hmm, after I found out about `expand("<cWORD>")`, I expected something like those special expressions.. This answer is quite easy and straightforwart indeed, thank you.